# Filter xml by node value in php

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I have an xml that shows Arriving and departing flights, we have to sort this in different columns based on the "type" (arriving or departure) values in the xml file. How do i do this?

Xml looks like this:

```
<flights>
<flight>
<iata>ND812</iata>
<name>NDA812</name>
<type>arrival</type>
<airline>
<name>Nordica</name>
</airline>
<remark/>
 <airport>
   <name>Airport 1</name>
<localname/>
</airport>
<scheduleddate>2022-06-21</scheduleddate>
<scheduledtime>10:35</scheduledtime>
</flight>

<flight>
<iata>ND812</iata>
<name>NDA812</name>
<type>departure</type>
<airline>
<name>Nordica</name>
</airline>
<remark/>
 <airport>
   <name>Airport 2</name>
<localname/>
</airport>
<scheduleddate>2022-06-21</scheduleddate>
<scheduledtime>10:35</scheduledtime>
</flight>
</flights>
```

Were using PHPCode snippets plugin in WP

```
// load SimpleXML
$flight = new SimpleXMLElement('https://XXX/fids.xml', null, true);

echo $flight ->flight[0]->type."<br />";
echo $flight ->flight[1]->type."<br />";
echo $flight ->flight[2]->type."<br />";
```

This obviously shows all flights arriving and departure....

Grateful for quick help!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply loop on each flight. Then you can test the flight type to do whatever you want. I'm not sure I understand: "we have to sort this in different columns based on the type".

```
<?php
$response = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<flights>
<flight>
<iata>ND812</iata>
<name>NDA812</name>
<type>arrival</type>
<airline>
<name>Nordica</name>
</airline>
<remark/>
 <airport>
   <name>Airport 1</name>
<localname/>
</airport>
<scheduleddate>2022-06-21</scheduleddate>
<scheduledtime>10:35</scheduledtime>
</flight>
<flight>
<iata>ND812</iata>
<name>NDA812</name>
<type>departure</type>
<airline>
<name>Nordica</name>
</airline>
<remark/>
 <airport>
   <name>Airport 2</name>
<localname/>
</airport>
<scheduleddate>2022-06-21</scheduleddate>
<scheduledtime>10:35</scheduledtime>
</flight>
</flights>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

foreach ($xml->flight as $flight) {
   if($flight->type=='departure') {
    echo $flight->type, ' / ', $flight->name, ' / ', $flight->airport->name, ' / ', $flight->iata, ' / ', $flight->remark, ' / ', $flight->scheduleddate, PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

Results

```
departure / NDA812 / Airport 2 / ND812 /  / 2022-06-21
```

Comment: Sorry...was so tired maybe i was unclear. I need to show all arriving airplanes in one table and departure in another. So what i need is really a way to sort out say all departure info in the first step.  I have figured out all of the other data its only the "filtering" of arrival and departure i cant get my head around.

Comment: No problem. So, my answer seems to answer your question, no? Since I show you the way to loop through all the flights, then according to their type in the if condition, to do the treatment you want.

Comment: Maybe im missing something but im getting this outout when i try: arrival / NDA812 arrival / NDA816 | departure / NDA812 Gällivare Airport | departure / NDA816 Gällivare Airport. So the arriving airplane is also showing up. I really really appreciate your help..im no coder so i struggle with this!! And how do i add the other fields like <iata><remark> and so on to your code?

Comment: Just remove the first echo from the loop. I updated my answer.
The code you are interested in is the if in the foreach loop. If the type is departure then I echo the xml values. In this if statement you can do whatever you want. You only have departures.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer suits you, please don't forget to click on "accept the answer" and vote by clicking on the top arrow "the answer is useful".

Comment: @Mattias...for memory